# ASP Identity in MVC6 - Login Path property not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

After updating from beta 5 to beta 8 I can't set my custom login path in cookie authentication options.

```
services.AddCookieAuthentication(config =>
{
    config.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
    //or
    //config.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("Auth/Login");
});
```

This value is completely ignored. Still gets redirected to the default '*/Account/Login*'. Is there any other options to set this path?

Comment: Works on my end... you can try setting `AutomaticAuthentication = true` if you don't have it set. If that doesn't work, clear out the `artifacts/` folder, I've noticed a few times things being cached and causing problems.

Comment: I set this option to true, but still the same problem. Even I created a new project and no differences.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that now you should do this a bit differently (worked for me):

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options=>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString("/Auth/Login");
});
```

From [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/539#issuecomment-149651741).

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution works like expected.

Comment: It did not work for me. I am using AspNetCore. Any idea?