# ASPCore, redirect fail CookieAuthenticationOptions LoginPath

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core

I want to redirect user when he want access to [Autorize] controller.

I'm using UseCookieAuthentication. It's work well but LoginPath do not redirect my request. I alway got "401 Unauthorized" (i.e. empty page).

Below my code:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
            CookieName = "bearerCookies",
            TicketDataFormat = new CustomJwtDataFormat(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, tokenValidationParameters),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
        });
```

But i tried to add event like this post : [Modify CookieAuthenticationOptions LoginPath OnRedirectToReturnUrl Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36663763/modify-cookieauthenticationoptions-loginpath-onredirecttoreturnurl-event) i even set break point in this event i do not enter in this function!

I also tried this way [ASP Identity in MVC6 - Login Path property not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247054/asp-identity-in-mvc6-login-path-property-not-working)

But is not fixe for aspnetcore. I update my package too, as i read on some forum

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0"
```

anyone got this issue? have you any idea? i just want a simple redirection :)

thank you everyone

Comment: Do you have `[AllowAnonymous]` on that login route/controller? Or is it that you get no redirect at all in the browser (check F12 tools)?

Comment: hello yes yes i have `[AllowAnonymous]`, when i checked F12 i saw (`401 Unauthorized`). no redirect at all :S